Oracle Apex Double Horizontala Scrollbar on Classic Report
Have a page with a faceted search region + a classic report with a basic query.
I'm trying to add a second scrollbar on top so user has two (one at top, another in bottom).
Using this code to no avail, anyone has any idea?
(report Static Id 'admin')
JS:
function DoubleScroll(element) {
  var scrollbar = document.createElement('div');
  scrollbar.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  scrollbar.style.overflow = 'auto';
  scrollbar.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
  scrollbar.firstChild.style.width = element.scrollWidth+'px';
  scrollbar.firstChild.style.paddingTop = '1px';
  scrollbar.firstChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\xA0'));
  scrollbar.onscroll = function() {
      element.scrollLeft = scrollbar.scrollLeft;
  };
  element.onscroll = function() {
      scrollbar.scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft;
  };
  element.parentNode.insertBefore(scrollbar, element);
}

DoubleScroll(document.getElementById('admin'));

CSS:
#admin {overflow: auto; overflow-y: hidden;}

Thanks
